# Pentaho Kettle - How to update null values

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to transform table 1 into table 2 via Pentaho Kattle, but I'm not getting it:

```
t1
---
null
null
1
null
null
null
2
...
```

to

```
t1
---
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
...
```

what step can I use?

I tried using java modified but I couldn't get the result. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Not sure... You can look back N rows with analytics step, or spread columns downwards on text input by the repeat option, but reading an undetermined amount of rows forward to a value.... might be tough... I can think of an ugly sollution. Will put it in, since it will work, but not very nice.

Answer (score 0):

To transform `t1` from table 1 to table 2 as shown, you can achieve it using Pentaho Data Integration (PDI), formerly known as Kettle. PDI is a powerful tool for data integration and transformation.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to transform `t1`:

Step 1: Read Data from File or others

- Use the "Text File Input" step in PDI to read the data from `t1`. Set the delimiter as a new line or any other suitable separator based on your input format.

Step 2: Sort Data

- Use the "Sort Rows" step to sort the data in ascending order. This will bring all the non-null values together.

Step 3: Group Data

- Use the "Group By" step to group the data based on the non-null values. This will create groups of consecutive non-null rows.

Step 4: Generate Rows

- Use the "Generate Rows" step to duplicate each row in each group based on the number of non-null values in that group. You can use the "Group Size" field to achieve this.

Step 5: Fill Null Values

- Use the "Replace Value" step to replace null values in the output with the corresponding non-null value from the previous row. This will effectively fill the null values with the corresponding non-null values.

Step 6: Write Data to output

- Use the "Text File Output" step to write the transformed data to the desired destination.

By following these steps, you should be able to transform `t1` from table 1 to table 2 as described. Each non-null value will be repeated in the output based on the number of null values preceding it in the input.

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: No idea how this could work... the moment you sort in step 2, you already lose the order of rows, based on which you need to update id the id field. Once you lose this order, you can't fill the id anymore. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but if so, please add an example so it is less abstract.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you need to spread the id upwards, which is not possible (as far as i know) for a not constant number of rows. At least not with the standard steps. You can either itterate with an analytics step for N=1 backwards, or do the quick and dirty sollution:

Just load with a row number, sort descending on rownumber (so last record is then first and vice versa), overwrite the file in reverse order, and then load with repeat on. It will solve the issue, but is not the nicest sollution.